# Finding consecutive elements of an array using Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm almost new at Java! I want to control if there are 4 consecutive elements in an array with 5 elements. Is there any way to do that? Can someone help me with that? Thanks! Consecutive like `{2, 3, 4, 5}`. If there is `{3, 4, 2, 5}` for example this is not consecutive.I want just a simple example if someone can help me.

I did this but I think this is incorrect:

```java
 public int katerTeNjepasnjeshme()
 {
         int[] numrat=new int[zar.length];
         for(int i=0;i<zar.length;i++)
             numrat[i]=zar[i].getValue();
         int shuma=0;
         for(int i=0;i<zar.length-1;i++)
         {


    if(zar[i+1].getValue()==(zar[i].getValue()+1))
         Joptionpane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tere are cons elements");
}
```

Comment: constructiveness is calculated by formula a[i+1] = a[i] +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the general idea:
Keep a counter (initialized appropriately), to keep track of the number of consecutive elements as you iterate over the elements.
If the counter reaches 4, you have found 4 consecutive elements.
If you encounter an element that is not consecutive, then reset the counter to 1, and proceed to check the next element.

Here is a sample code snippet:

```
public static void findConsecutive()
    {
        int[] array = {1,2,3,5,6,7,8,10};

        int counter = 1;
        int i = 1;
        for (i = 1; i < array.length; i++)
        {
            if (array[i] == (array[i-1] + 1))
            {
                counter++;
                if (counter == 4)
                {
                    System.out.println("Consecutive elements are at array index: " + (i - 3) + " to " + i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                counter = 1;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Doen - Added a sample code to explain the steps listed.

Answer (score 1):

i think something like that should work:

```
int[] mylist = new int[10];

for (int i = 0; i < myList.length; i++) {
    int k = 1;
    for (int j = 1; j < 5 j++) {
        if (mylist[i] == mylist[i+j]-j) {
            k++;
        }
        if (k=5) System.out.println("found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you need to  compare two elements of the array you should use proper bounds in the loop, otherwise you will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
boolean consequtive = true;
for (int i = 0; i < zar.length - 1; i++)                                 
    if (zar[i+1].getValue() != zar[i].getValue() + 1) {
        consecutive = false;
        break;
    }    
if (consequtive)
    Joptionpane.showMessageDialog(null,"Tere are cons elements");
```